# Unexpected results when using tfrecords loaded using tf.data.Dataset.list_files() with shuffle argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I'm hoping to get clarification on how the `shuffle` argument in `tf.data.Dataset.list_files()` works. The documentation states that when `shuffle=True`, the filenames will be shuffled randomly. I've made model predictions using a tfrecords dataset that has been loaded using `tf.data.Dataset.list_files()`, and I would've expected the accuracy metric to be the same no matter the order of the files (i.e. whether shuffle is True or False), but am seeing otherwise.

Is this expected behavior or is there something wrong with my code or intepretation? I have reproducible example code below.

Oddly, as long as `tf.random.set_random_seed()` is set initially (and it seems it doesn't even matter what seed value is set), then the predictions results are the same no matter whether shuffle is True or False in `list_files()`.

tensorflow==1.13.1, keras==2.2.4

Thanks for any clarifications!

Edit: re-thinking it through and wondering if `Y = [y[0] for _ in range(steps) for y in sess.run(Y)]` is a separate and independent call?

```
# Fit and Save a Dummy Model
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.random.set_random_seed(seed)

dataset = datasets.load_iris()

X = dataset.data
Y = dataset.target
dummy_Y = np_utils.to_categorical(Y)

# 150 rows
print(len(X))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, dummy_Y, epochs=10, batch_size=10,  verbose=2)
model.save('./iris/iris_model')

predictions = model.predict(X)
predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

# returns accuracy = 0.3466666666666667
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_true=Y, y_pred=predictions))
```

Split dataset into multiple tfrecords files so we can reload it with list_files() later:

```
numrows = 15
for i, j in enumerate(range(0, len(X), numrows)):
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('./iris/iris{}.tfrecord'.format(i)) as writer:
        for x, y in zip(X[j:j+numrows, ], Y[j:j+numrows, ]):
            features = tf.train.Features(feature=
                {'X': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=x)), 
                'Y': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[y]))
                })
            example = tf.train.Example(features=features)
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

At this point, I exit (ipython) and restart again:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn import metrics

model = load_model('./iris/iris_model')

batch_size = 10
steps = int(150/batch_size)
file_pattern = './iris/iris*.tfrecord'

feature_description = {
    'X': tf.FixedLenFeature([4], tf.float32),
    'Y': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64)
}

def _parse_function(example_proto):
    return tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)

def load_data(filenames, batch_size):
    raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = raw_dataset.map(_parse_function)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    record = iterator.get_next()
    return record['X'], record['Y']

def get_predictions_accuracy(filenames):
    X, Y = load_data(filenames=filenames, batch_size=batch_size)

    predictions = model.predict([X], steps=steps)
    predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
    print(len(predictions))

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        Y = [y[0] for _ in range(steps) for y in sess.run(Y)]

    print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_true=Y, y_pred=predictions))
```

```
# No shuffle results:
# Returns expected accuracy = 0.3466666666666667
filenames_noshuffle = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern=file_pattern, shuffle=False)
get_predictions_accuracy(filenames_noshuffle)
```

```
# Shuffle results, no seed value set:
# Returns UNEXPECTED accuracy (non-deterministic value)
filenames_shuffle_noseed = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern=file_pattern, shuffle=True)
get_predictions_accuracy(filenames_shuffle_noseed)
```

```
# Shuffle results, seed value set:
# Returns expected accuracy = 0.3466666666666667
# It seems like it doesn't even matter what seed value you set, as long as you you set it
seed = 1000
tf.random.set_random_seed(seed)
filenames_shuffle_seed = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern=file_pattern, shuffle=True)
get_predictions_accuracy(filenames_shuffle_seed)
```

Comment: Was able to answer my own question - it was in fact due to `Y = [y[0] for _ in range(steps) for y in sess.run(Y)]` being a separate and independent call